# Parse Master Key Not Working In Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, key, cloud

I wrote a small script recently to increment a column count in my Parse Cloud code using afterSave() and it worked fine. However after changing my ACLs and using my master key as suggested in the Parse documentation, I keep on getting the error:

```
Error: Cannot use the Master Key, it has not been provided.
```

I'm using Parse.initialize(userId, jsKey, masterKey) and I've tried using Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); in my afterSave() method and I've tried using { useMasterKey: true } in my save() method. Is this a bug? Any help would be appreciated.